# Reporting Server Home Page Only displays When Run as Administrator

Tags: reporting-services, installation, ssrs-2008

I am having some issues setting up Reporting Server. I can open http://localhost/reports only when I run Internet Explorer as administrator. When I try to open it from another server, logging in with the same user as the service account, I get prompted for credentials before it proceeds. What settings do I need to check\change to allow me to open the reports home page without having to open IE as administrator locally or having to enter my username and password from a remote connection? Here is the error I am receiving if I open IE not as admin.

*User 'DOMAIN\USER' does not have required permissions. Verify that sufficient permissions have been granted and Windows User Account Control (UAC) restrictions have been addressed.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connect to SSRS Report Manager (/reports) as admin, then check what you see when you click on the Folder Settings. This should give you the security settings for the root folder. Make sure that your account is included here, whether by AD group or individually. Content Manager is the most permissive setting.

Comment: Thanks, This works perfectly for allowing me to run reports on the local server without having to run IE as admin. But when I still cannot access the reports from a remote server even when logged in as the reports admin user

Comment: This is likely due to your IE settings: Are you allowing credentials to be passed for whatever zone this site is in? Try putting the report server in your trusted sites.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to checking the Home folder security settings as #Jamie-F pointed out, check the "Site Settings", "Security" as well and make sure the user or group is there.

Comment: True, if SSRS is SharePoint integrated. Original question sounds like it isn't.

Comment: This was 100% the step I needed for just one of my servers!